# Ormlite like query on map of fields

Tags: mapping, ormlite

I've been using ORMLite for close to a year now and I find it is excellent, it's simple and it works.

I have a project requirement to implement a broad search function- the user enters a value and ANY matching field in the table should be returned (POJOs). Tables have a simple 1:1 relationship with Java objects.

I can achieve this for a KNOWN class using the queryBuilder().where().like(...) however, I would like to build a generic dynamic function for all child classes.

All my persistent classes derive from a "Persistent" base class which has some basic housekeeping, handles store and delete for an individual object. This is where I am putting the "find" function, which ideally returns either an Iterator or a List<T>, preferably an Iterator.

I've already got a Map<String, DataType> for all DatabaseField annotated Fields. **Right now, I just want a "brute" force is string "X" present anywhere in field Y**. I'll figure out data type conversions and checking later. If I can build the query dynamically, then I can resolve the data typing issue in the next version.

I've looked at the methods that take maps as parameters and they are a narrow match, i.e. all must match. I am looking for the opposite: any match will do.

The only method I can think of is to build individual "like" components and string them together into a larger statement, from the documentation, I can't figure out how to do that dynamically.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've messed with some code, and this achieves what I want- but I would very much welcome comments to improve or suggest better ways of achieving the intended outcome.

```
 protected QueryBuilder<T, Long> getQuery(String text, boolean wide, boolean count) {
      if (null == fields)
         reflectKeyInfo();

      QueryBuilder<T, Long> qb = null;

      if (count)
         qb = getDao().queryBuilder().setCountOf(true);
      else
         qb = getDao().queryBuilder();

      if (null == qb)
         return null;

      Where<T, Long> where = qb.where();

      boolean equals = text.contains("=") ;
      boolean like   = text.contains("~") ;

      if (equals || like)  {
         String field = null ;
         String value = null ;

         try {
            if (equals) {
               field = Strings.left(text, text.indexOf("=")) ;
               value = Strings.right(text, text.indexOf("=")) ;

               if (Strings.isValid(field) && Strings.isValid(value))
                  where.eq(field, value) ;
            }
            else
               if (like) {
                  field = Strings.left(text, text.indexOf("~")) ;
                  value = Strings.right(text, text.indexOf("~")) ;

                  if (Strings.isValid(field) && Strings.isValid(value))
                     where.like(field, "%" + value + "%") ;
               }
            }
         catch (SQLException e) {
            lastError = GlobalConfig.log(e, true) ;
            Dialogs.alert("Query Failed",
                               "<br />Unable to extract field and value from " +
                               field + "=" + value + "<br />" + lastError) ;
         }
      }
      else
         for (String field : fields.keySet()) {
            try {
               if (fields.get(field).isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                  if (wide)
                     where.like(field, "%" + text + "%");
                  else
                     where.eq(field, text);

                  where.or();
               }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
               lastError = GlobalConfig.log(e, true);
            }
         } // for
      return qb;
  }
```

Comment: This looks like it would work.  One thing to consider is that you can submit a number of `eq(...)` or `like(...)` clauses together with the `Where.or(int)` command.  So you keep a count of the number of `eq` or `like` clauses and then just do `where.or(clauseCount)` which will string them all together with SQL `OR`.